# Can anyone comment this hadith?

Tags: hadith, authenticity

> #### سبعة لا ينظرالله إليهم يوم القيامة ولا يزكيهم، ويقول: ادخلوا النار مع الداخلين: الفاعل والمفعول به، والناكح يده، وناكح البهيمة، وناكح المرأة في دبرها، وجامع بين المرأة وابنتها، والزاني بحليلة جاره، والمؤذي جاره حتى يلعنه
>
> The Prophet (pbuh) said, "On the Day of Judgment, there will be seven
> people who will be excluded from Allah's Mercy and purification. Allah
> will sentence them to enter the Hell-Fire with those who enter it:
> Those who commit sodomy, the one who commits masturbation, the one who
> approaches an animal from its anus, the one who approaches a woman
> from her anus, the one who marries a woman and her daughter
> altogether, the adulterer of his neighbor's wife and the one who
> brings harm to his neighbor until he accurse him.”
>
> <sup>— [Tafsir Ibn Kathir](http://quran.ksu.edu.sa/tafseer/katheer/sura2-aya223.html)</sup>

I need a clarification of the authenticity of the hadith, this hadith is a Gharib hadith and it takes about the ruling of Sodomy... in many ruling of Sodomy & Zina, I have to not encountered this hadith. Even in IslamQA when giving the ruling for masturbation, this hadith was not mentioned. Can anyone plz help me, understand the authenticity of a Gharib hadith.

Comment: I need a clarification of the authenticity of the hadith, this hadith is a Gharib hadith and it takes about the ruling of Sodomy... in many ruling of Sodomy & Zina, I have to not encountered this hadith. Even in IslamQA when giving the ruling for masturbation, this hadith was not mentioned.

Comment: Alt version [here](http://quran.ksu.edu.sa/tafseer/katheer/sura23-aya6.html#katheer) which is perhaps the one called Gharib.

Answer (score 3):

The hadith you have quoted is weak as Ibn Kathir after citing the hadith wrote about its chain:

> ابن لهيعة وشيخه ضعيفان
>
> Ibn Luhay‘ah and his teacher are weak

Comment: Thank you for comment!!!

Comment: Also can you provide references to the pdf if possible, of the tafsir of Ibn Kathir, where he mentions "Ibn Luhay‘ah and his teacher are weak", I'd like to read the section for my self. Thx again.

Comment: @TouhidRifat The arabic is linked to in your question. Here is the link: http://quran.ksu.edu.sa/tafseer/katheer/sura2-aya223.html

Comment: Thank you for the link, unfortunately I can't really read arabic. Can I clarify, which part of the link is the quote. Thanks for the help again.

Comment: You have the text and the link on which it is found, you can use your browser to get to the specific part. I can't make it any more clear.

Answer (score 3):

**The hadith narration at first sight**

The hadith is gharib from different points of view and sounds like a fabrication:

- The hadith was only transmitted on the authority of two sahabah Anas ibn Malik أنس بن مالك (as a marfo' hadith) and 'Abdullah ibn 'Amr عبد الله بن عمرو.
- The hadith narrator chain has a lot of issues (unknown and not reliable narrators)
- The wording at the beginning of the hadith seems to be chosen to sound similar to the hadith of the 7 who will be shaded by Allah's shade:

  > "Seven (people) will be shaded by Allah by His Shade on the Day of Resurrection when there will be no shade except His Shade. (They will be), a just ruler, a young man who has been brought up in the worship of Allah, a man who remembers Allah in seclusion and his eyes are then flooded with tears, a man whose heart is attached to mosques (offers his compulsory congregational prayers in the mosque), two men who love each other for Allah's Sake, a man who is called by a charming lady of noble birth to commit illegal sexual intercourse with her, and he says, 'I am afraid of Allah,' and (finally), a man who gives in charity so secretly that his left hand does not know what his right hand has given."
  > ([Sahih al-Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:6806), [Sahih Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim/12/117), [al-Muwatta'](https://sunnah.com/urn/517260), [Sunan an-Nasa-i](https://sunnah.com/nasai/49/2) and [Jami' at-Tirmidhi](https://sunnah.com/tirmidhi/36/88))

**Sources of the narration**

The hadith was compiled in some sources:

- On the authority of Anas ibn Malik: in the Juz' جزء -see [here](https://www.islamweb.net/hadith/display_hbook.php?bk_no=153&pid=816425&hid=38) in Arabic- of Al-Hassan ibn 'Arafah [أبو علي الحسن بن عرفة](https://ar.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%AD%D8%B3%D9%86_%D8%A8%D9%86_%D8%B9%D8%B1%D9%81%D8%A9). Ibn al-Jawzi  ابن الجوزي transferred the hadith from this source in his al-'Ilal al-Mutanahiyyah العلل المتناهية (which is a book on weaknesses in ahadith), Al-Bayhaqi البيهقي in his Sho'ab al-Iman شعب الإيمان and [al-Ajurri](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abu_Bakr_al-Ajurri) الآجري in his book condemning sodomy called Dham al-Liwat ذم اللواط -see [here](https://library.islamweb.net/hadith/display_hbook.php?indexstartno=0&hflag=1&pid=279393&bk_no=467&startno=1) in Arabic- did the same. The narrator chain of this narration is the following:
   <sub>In the following I'll translate from Arabic, as these translations are of my own take them with the necessary care!</sub>

  > حدثني علي بن ثابت الجزري ، عن مسلمة بن جعفر ، عن حسان بن حميد ، عن أنس بن مالك ، عن النبي صلى الله عليه وسلم
  >  <sub>I will try to add some informations on the narrators between brackets</sub>
  >
  > - I was informed by *'Ali ibn Thabit al-Jazari* (Was among the teachers of Ahamd ibn Hanbal he is considered as trustworthy however al-Azdi considers him da'if ibn Ma'yn made some details)
  > - from *Maslamah ibn Ja'afar* (accepted "مقبول" again al-Azdi is among those who considered him da'if)
  > - from *Hassan ibn Humaid* (unknown)
  > - from *Anas ibn Malik* from *the Prophet* Allah's prayers and blessings be upon him

  In fatwa islamqa #[129118](https://islamqa.info/ar/answers/129118/%D9%87%D9%84-%D8%AA%D8%B3%D8%AA%D8%AC%D8%A7%D8%A8-%D8%AA%D9%88%D8%A8%D8%A9-%D9%85%D9%86-%D8%A7%D8%A8%D8%AA%D9%84%D9%8A-%D8%A8%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B9%D8%A7%D8%AF%D8%A9-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B3%D8%B1%D9%8A%D8%A9) -in Arabic- this chain was qualified as:

  > وهذا إسناد ضعيف جدا .
  > And this narrator chain is very weak (da'if jiddan).
- On the authority of 'Abdullah ibn 'Amr: It was compiled by al-Ajurri in the book quoted above as hadith #53 -see [here](https://library.islamweb.net/hadith/display_hbook.php?indexstartno=0&hflag=1&pid=279393&bk_no=467&startno=0) in Arabic-, and by ibn Bisharan [ابن بشران](https://ar.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D8%A3%D8%A8%D9%88_%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%82%D8%A7%D8%B3%D9%85_%D8%A8%D9%86_%D8%A8%D8%B4%D8%B1%D8%A7%D9%86) in his al-Amaali الأمالي according to al-Mundhiri it was narrated by [ibn abi ad-Dunya](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ibn_Abi_al-Dunya) and [al-Kharaiti](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muhammad_ibn_Ja%27far_al-Khara%27iti) and others and mentioned that it is weak.
  As for the narrator chain of al-Ajurri it goes as follwos:

  > قال  جعفر الفريابي  : حدثنا قتيبة ، حدثنا ابن لهيعة ، عن  عبد الرحمن بن زياد بن أنعم ، عن أبي عبد الرحمن الحبلي ، عن عبد الله بن عمرو قال : قال رسول الله صلى الله عليه وسلم
  >  <sub>I will try to add some informations on the narrators between brackets</sub>
  > *Ja'afar al-Firyabi* (trustworthy with a high level of trust)
  > from *Qutaybah* (ibn Sa'id is considered as trustworthy)
  > from abu Lahi'a ('Abdullah widely considred as da'if as he was forgetting and writting down his hadith)
  > from *'Abdurrahman ibn Ziyad ibn 'Anu'm* ( is considered as weak especially as he often narrated rejected -munkar- hadith)
  > from *abu 'Abdarrahman al-Hubuli* (is considered as trustwothy)
  > from *'Abdullah ibn 'Amr* who said that the *Prophet* Allahs prayers and blessings said ..

**Authenticity and qualifications a deeper look**

In his tafsir of verse 2:223 ibn Kathir quoted this hadith from Ja'afar al-Firyabi on the authority of 'Abdullah ibn 'Amr with the wording (around page 594)

> " سبعة لا ينظر الله إليهم يوم القيامة ولا يزكيهم ، ويقول : ادخلوا النار مع الداخلين : الفاعل والمفعول به ، والناكح يده ، وناكح البهيمة ، وناكح المرأة في دبرها ، وجامع بين المرأة وابنتها ، والزاني بحليلة جاره ، والمؤذي جاره حتى يلعنه "

and commented it saying:

> ابن لهيعة وشيخه ضعيفان .(Source tafsir ibn Kathir [تفسير ابن كثير](https://www.islamweb.net/newlibrary/display_book.php?idfrom=190&idto=190&bk_no=49&ID=194))
> Ibn Lahi'a and his teacher (sheikh) are (both) weak.

This goes ahead with the conclusion of al-Albani in his as-Silsilah ad-Da'ifah (the weak series) which is quoted in islamqa #129118 quoted above and includes the statement of al-Mundhiri about this hadith in the given variation.

In his tafsir of verse 23:6 ibn Kathir quotes this hadith from Juz' ibn 'Arafah with the wording:

> " سبعة لا ينظر الله إليهم يوم القيامة ، ولا يزكيهم ، ولا يجمعهم مع العاملين ، ويدخلهم النار أول الداخلين ، إلا أن يتوبوا ، فمن تاب تاب الله عليه : ناكح يده ، والفاعل ، والمفعول به ، ومدمن الخمر ، والضارب والديه حتى يستغيثا ، والمؤذي جيرانه حتى يلعنوه ، والناكح حليلة جاره "  .

and comments it:

> هذا حديث غريب ، وإسناده فيه من لا يعرف لجهالته ، والله أعلم . (Source tafsir ibn Kathir [تفسير ابن كثير](https://www.islamweb.net/newlibrary/display_book.php?idfrom=1231&idto=1254&bk_no=49&ID=1255))
> This is hadith is gharib.  The narrator chain (isnaad) includes narrators who are not identified as they are unknown. and Allah knows best.

Imam a-Dhahabi says in his Mizan al-'itidal ميزان الاعتدال .

> [8518](http://madrasato-mohammed.com/dahbi/Page_011_0004.htm) - مسلمة بن جعفر.
> عن حسان بن حميد، عن أنس في سب الناكح يده.
> يجهل هو وشيخه.
> وقال [الازدي](https://ar.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D8%A3%D8%A8%D9%88_%D8%B2%D9%83%D8%B1%D9%8A%D8%A7_%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%A3%D8%B2%D8%AF%D9%8A): ضعيف.
> Maslamah ibn ja'afar from Hassan ibn Humayd from Anas on cursing the one who masturbates he (Maslamah) and his teacher (sheikh) are unknown. And al-Azdi said: da'if.

Al-Bayhaqi commented the hadith in his Sho'ab by.

> قال  البيهقي : تفرد به  مسلمة بن جعفر
> Al-Bayhaqi said: Maslamah was singular with it <sup>(1)</sup>. (Source [Sho'ab al-Iman](http://islamport.com/l/mtn/1349/5545.htm))
> <sup>(2) means he was the only one who transmitted this narration.</sup>

Ibn al-Jawzi says in his al-'Ilal al-Mutanahiyah

> قال المؤلف : "هذا حديث لا يصح عن رسول الله صلى الله عليه وسلم ، ولا حسان يعرف ، ولا مسلمة (Source [al-'Ilal al-Mutanahiyah](http://www.al-eman.com/%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%83%D8%AA%D8%A8/%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B9%D9%84%D9%84%20%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%85%D8%AA%D9%86%D8%A7%D9%87%D9%8A%D8%A9%20%D9%81%D9%8A%20%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%A3%D8%AD%D8%A7%D8%AF%D9%8A%D8%AB%20%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%88%D8%A7%D9%87%D9%8A%D8%A9/%D8%AD%D8%AF%D9%8A%D8%AB%20%D9%81%D9%8A%20%D9%81%D8%B6%D9%84%20%D9%85%D9%86%20%D9%84%D8%A7%D9%8E%20%D8%A3%D9%87%D9%84%20%D9%84%D9%87%20%D9%88%D9%84%D8%A7%20%D9%88%D9%84%D8%AF%20%D8%A8%D8%B9%D8%AF%20%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%85%D9%90%D8%A7%D8%A6%D9%8E%D8%AA%D9%8A%D9%86%D9%90:/i487&d614012&c&p1) a hadith on masturbation حديث في الاستمناء)
> This hadith is not sane (has no authentic sane chain) to the Messenger of Allah Allah's prayers and blessings be upon him, neither Hassan is known nor is Maslamah known.

Further more scholars as ibn al-Mulqin and ibn Hajar confirm that this hadith must be considered as dai'f and not authentic.